# Why Jackson in Quarkus can't deserialize a GeoLatte geometry?

Tags: java, jackson, geometry, quarkus

In Quarkus I'm trying to use GeoLatte Geometry in a DTO as follows:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@RegisterForReflection
public class TrackDTO {

    ...

    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private Geometry<C2D> geom;

    ...
}
```

I created a `JacksonConfig` class too:

```
@Singleton
public class JacksonConfig implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new GeolatteGeomModule());
    }
}
```

but If I try to push a geometry:

```
http http://localhost:8080/tracks \
        geom:="{ \"type\": \"point\", \"coordinates\": [ 1, 1 ] }"
```

It says me that:

```
2022-09-24 23:38:51,933 SEVERE [org.ecl.yas.int.Unmarshaller] (executor-thread-0) Unable to deserialize property 'geom' because of: Cannot create instance of a class: class org.geolatte.geom.Geometry, No default constructor found.
```

In my `build.gradle` I have these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jaxb'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-data-jpa'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'

    implementation 'com.github.fmcejudo:quarkus-eureka:0.0.14'

    implementation 'net.postgis:postgis-jdbc:2021.1.0'
//    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:6.1.3.Final'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55:2.19.2'

    implementation 'org.geolatte:geolatte-geom:1.8.2'
    implementation 'org.geolatte:geolatte-geojson:1.8.2'
}
```

How can I solve it?

---

EDIT:

I have the following Resource:

```
@Resource
@Path("/tracks")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TrackResource {

    @Inject
    TrackService trackService;


    @POST
    @Path("")
    public void saveTrack(TrackDTO trackDTO) {

        trackService.saveTrack(trackDTO);
    }
}
```

that call this Service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TrackService {

    private final TrackRepository trackRepository;
    private final TrackMapper trackMapper;

    public TrackService(TrackRepository trackRepository, TrackMapper trackMapper) {
        this.trackRepository = trackRepository;
        this.trackMapper = trackMapper;
    }


    public void saveTrack(TrackDTO trackDTO) {

        trackRepository.save(trackMapper.toEntity(trackDTO));
    }
}
```

with this Mapper:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TrackMapper {

    public TrackDTO toDTO(Track track) {

        return new TrackDTO()
                .setId(track.getId())
                .setGeom(track.getGeom())
                ;
    }

    public List<TrackDTO> toDTO(List<Track> tracks) {
        return tracks.stream().map(this::toDTO).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Track toEntity(TrackDTO trackDTO) {

        return new Track()
                .setId(trackDTO.getId())
                .setGeom(trackDTO.getGeom())
                ;
    }

    public List<Track> toEntity(List<TrackDTO> trackDTOs) {
        return trackDTOs.stream().map(this::toEntity).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code that actually tries to deserialize the data?

Comment: I edited the question, if that was the code you were asking for.

Comment: The error message comes from `org.ecl.yas.int.Unmarshaller` (that is, Eclipse Yasson, a JSON-B implementation), so Jackson is not used. The dependencies contain both `resteasy-jackson` and `resteasy-jsonb`, so it seems JSON-B is preferred.

Comment: without `implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb'` dependency it says me `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Class org.geolatte.geom.json.GeometryDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
 at [Source: (io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health'
//    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jaxb'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-data-jpa'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'

    implementation 'com.github.fmcejudo:quarkus-eureka:0.0.14'

    implementation 'net.postgis:postgis-jdbc:2021.1.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.6.4.Final'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55:2.19.2'

    implementation 'org.geolatte:geolatte-geom:1.8.2'
    implementation 'org.geolatte:geolatte-geojson:1.8.2'
}
```

and the DTO:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
// @RegisterForReflection
public class TrackDTO {

    private Long id;
    ...

//    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
//    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private Geometry<C2D> geom;
    ...
}
```

it works!

Comment: So you didnt need the `@JsonDeserializer` and `@JsonSerializer` ?